# enable/disable checkbox in IE

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i want to enable/disable checkbox using jQuery. I am using

```
$("#checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
```

This works fine in FF but not in IE.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

is correct **and** better

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

or if you are using jquery 1.6+

```
$("#checkbox").prop("disabled", true);
```